# VSCode API: How does workspace.getConfiguration work?

Tags: typescript, configuration, vscode-extensions

I was reading through the VSCode API documentation, and I am not quite sure how the section argument for the getConfiguration method is derived. For example, I was looking through the following file https://github.com/yanxiaodi/vscode-translator-helper/blob/master/src/config.ts, and I am not sure how why the section argument is provided as "translatorHelper", when I cannot find translator helper anywhere else in the GitHub repository. I apologise if this question is trivial, or if I have missed out something in the documentation, but I have been trying to figure out why the example code in the link above works for a while now. Any help will be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Most importantly, `translatorHelper` is in the repository's `package.json`.  Here is an excerpt from the `contributes` section:

```json
"configuration": {
   "title": "Translator Helper",
   "properties": {
      "translatorHelper.api": {
         "type": "string",
         "default": "google",
         "enum": [
            "google",
            "google-cn"
         ],
etc.....
```

and more settings, i.e. configurations.  Note they are all `translatorHelper.xxxx` so if you are trying to retrieve a setting like that you would use:

```
export const getConfiguration = <T>(key: string) => {
  return workspace.getConfiguration('translatorHelper').get<T>(key);
};
```

where the `key` argument would be `api`, `sourceLanguage`, etc. which are all `translatorHelper.api` and similar.

Even the indirect calls like

```
export const getApiConfiguration = () => {
  return getConfiguration<string>('api') ?? 'google';
};
```

are really shorthand for the `getConfiguration(someKeyHere)` function.

So since the configurations were named `translatorHelper.something` in the `package.json` you would use `translatorHelper` as the `sectionID` in `getConfiguration()`. And in the Settings UI of vscode they will all be grouped under the section header `translaorHelper`.  If the settings had been identified as `translatorHelper.other.api` for example, you can use `translatorHelper.other` as the `sectionID`.